# Getting penultimate expression for constant $e$ shaped?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Usually, to prove that the constant e in the form of $(1+1/n)^n$ is between $2$ and $3$, it is first expressed in the form of a binomial expansion, and then a technique is used to shape every element as a fraction with the numerator being the multiplication of $(1-1/n)(1-2/n)...1$ and the denominator as $n!$ and finally to shape it as $1+1+1/2+1/2^2+...$ which will be computed by geometric progression to $1+2=3$, proving that $2<e<3$.

Now the stupid question follows!

What are the steps to shape the penultimate expression with exactly the same logic?

The very last expression is obvious. Starting from $\binom{n}{n}1/n^n$ we expand to $\frac{n(n-1)...(n-(n-1))}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^n}$ and finally we reason that "it is less than" $\frac{1(1-1/n)...(1-(n-2)/n)}{2^{n-1}}$ which is less than $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ where the denominator is $2$ to the power of $n-1$.

The penultimate expression in initial form is $\binom{n}{n-1}1/n^{n-1}$ as I understand, and the final form "is less than" $\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$, but what are middle expressions that connect these two by applying the common technique of $(1-(n-x)/n)$ format please?

Comment: To produce $a^{b+c}$ use curly brackets: a^{b+c}

Comment: $\binom{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n(n-1)!}{(n-1)!}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{n^{n-2}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$ for $n\geq 2$

Comment: Using $(1-x/n)$ technique makes calculation only harder: $\binom{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}=$ $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots 3\cdot 2}{n^{n-1}}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=$ $\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n}\ldots \frac{3}{n}\frac{2}{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)\ldots \cdot 3\cdot 2}=$ $1\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\ldots \left(1-\frac{n-2}{n}\right) \frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}\ldots\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\leq$  $1\cdot 1 \cdot 1 \ldots \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\ldots \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=$ $\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}$.